# Spring MVC: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'formData' available as request attribute

Tags: jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, spring-form

I am trying to redirect to a form from a controller but I get an error message : Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'formData' available as request attribute

My controller is

```
public class PrepareFormController implements Controller {



@Override
public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest arg0,
        HttpServletResponse arg1) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("PrepareFormController: handleRequest is called");
    return new ModelAndView("guestbook");
}
```

And the form is this one

```
<table>
<form:form>
    <tr>
        <td>Title :</td>
        <td><form:input path="title"/>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Text :</td>
        <td><form:input path="text"/>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Name :</td>
        <td><form:input path="name"/>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="right"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
    </tr>

</form:form>
```

This is what my app-servlet.xml file looks like :

```
<bean name="/guestbook.app" class="de.asd.TestController">
    <property name="model" ref="GuestBookModel"/>

    <property name="commandClass" value="de.asd.GuestBookCommand" />
</bean>

<bean name="/prepareFormController.app" class="de.asd.PrepareFormController">
    <property name="model" ref="GuestBookModel"/>
</bean>
```

Why is this happening ? If I access the guestbook.app directly then I don't get the error but I need to go through the controller.

Comment: The point of using `form` tag lib is to work with a model attribute. You have no model attribute on which to resolve the different `path` elements.

Comment: The class containing these path elements is called GuestBookCommand. If I change the <form:form> to <form:form modelAttribute="GuestBookCommand"> then I get again an error message. Do I have to do it differently ?

Comment: You misunderstand. Which class has fields `title`, `text`, and `name`. You need to add an instance of that class as a model attribute before the JSP gets rendered.

Comment: Ok now I understand , it is working correctly !! Se euxaristw !!

Comment: Na'sai kala. You're welcome.